# Error creating branch in CVS

Tags: branch, cvs

I have the following repository structure

```
/
|-- projects/
|    |-- projectA/
|    |    |-- moduleA/
|    |    |-- moduleB/
|    |    |-- moduleC/
|-- other_stuff
```

I want to create a branch from a particular tag for the `projectA`directory. So this are the commands I'm using and the output I get.

```
C:\>cvs login
Logging in to :ssh:myuser@myserver:22:/opt/cvs
CVS Password:

C:\>cvs tag -r TagToBranchFrom -b NewBranch projects/projectA 
cvs [tag aborted]: no such directory `projects'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should you not create the Branch folder earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cvs tag` which carries out actions on a working copy (ie. checked out project).

If you don't have the project checked out then you should use `cvs rtag` which works on the repository and doesn't require a working copy.